# Does OpenCV with CUDA require SSE4.2 on Windows?

Tags: opencv

I can't find any good information on compiling OpenCV. I've tried nearly everything and I'm stuck. 
My question is, does OpenCV require SSE4.2. That is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SSE is for CPU, nothing to do with GPU.

SSE stands for Streaming SIMD Extensions and utilizes 128-bit xmm registers in CPU. For more information, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Registers).

In Opencv, if building from source, you need to enable following options:

```
ENABLE_SSE
ENABLE_SSE2
ENABLE_SSE3
ENABLE_SSE41
ENABLE_SSE42
ENABLE_SSSE3
```

Note, enable the options which are supported by your hardware.

Quoted from [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93455-what-is-the-sse2-instruction-set-how-can-i-check-to-see-if-my-processor-supports-it) for windows(Not a window user):-

> **Windows** :- A free download, CPU-Z, is available from CPUID that will indicate if SSE2 is present on your system or not.

**OSX** :- Run `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu` and check both machdep.cpu.leaf7_features and machdep.cpu.features rows.

**Ubuntu**:- Run `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. This will display configuration of each code. You have to check "flags" row.

Finally,

Also enable AVX and AVX2 if supported using flags:

```
ENABLE_AVX
ENABLE_AVX2
```

Comment: another option on windows is to check `cpuinfo` from windows sub system

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV will optionally compile for whatever level of SSE is detected by cmake. This is independent of building CUDA support